# Firebase privacy policy

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-biometric-prompt, privacy-policy

I nearly finished my first app. I used Firebase authentication, Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Storage. I didn't find any good documentation or guide about how to write Privacy policy for android app. My question is should I inform the users that I used Firebase to store their data and images? I also use biometric authentication to login the app, should I also include this in my privacy policy?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be moved to law.stackexchange.com